Connect to amqp with jwt token
I use @cloudamqp/amqp-client library and set up rabbitmq server to use oauth2, how can I use jwt to connect to broker via websocket?
I tried make this - connection closed: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile., but obviously it doesn't work
const amqp = new AMQPWebSocketClient(
  "ws://localhost:15670?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IjNRR0Q5eU9aREhyaFBKaTdjQkg5WSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi0zN2l2aGxidDBhbjE3NHYyLnVzLmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJhdXRoMHw2Njc2YmFiODYxYjI2MWY2NDNhNmQ2YjQiLCJhdWQiOlsiaHR0cHM6Ly9kZXYtMzdpdmhsYnQwYW4xNzR2Mi51cy5hdXRoMC5jb20vYXBpL3YyLyIsImh0dHBzOi8vZGV2LTM3aXZobGJ0MGFuMTc0djIudXMuYXV0aDAuY29tL3VzZXJpbmZvIl0sImlhdCI6MTcxOTA1NzA4NCwiZXhwIjoxNzE5MDY0Mjg0LCJzY29wZSI6Im9wZW5pZCBwcm9maWxlIGVtYWlsIiwiYXpwIjoiWjNEbTBRWXhlbDREYkJZQ0ZzUDdYQTBtaEg5MklHaHYifQ.FsDJhUZ0ybiIV8C1pAxn6eDwlVoq6rVYcU6JywSU7Lm4sELz2LffzxJzxN_gabJHSh1C49WG5yU1LvLSep448u6sz5b7W2OSsHaCznolhc5T2JvjrYybtxD1Vph_eU8Aozb1ScfV-hz6W2emRloKh9kVTWUUUTzlpB5lE_L3GiEQExU6XWJy_GRbJ5bBA15nQmunDmtT-gQYKcYn1FSdyPwThQN_rr7UkfgSG_Yg-gsYIkl-X-qvvpJ0EtRIEuMn-n_OTfzB5sQhu6t5BLOI55pvK8g9pjIVNSHJGeD9RcnivmPKNas24SoCrSxKQAwMimLIraedysHLnoLsn1LqEw"
);

@cloudamqp/amqp-client version is 3.1.1
